# Starting rails server having error for a mysql project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i'm using ruby version 1.9.3 p448 and rails version 3.2.13
all of my gems are upto date.

i create a project with the following code `rails new simple_cms -d mysql`

but when I start rails server with code `rails s` / `rails server`

I got the following error

```
wasif@Bayaw:~/projects/Sites/simple_cms$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.13 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/home/wasif/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/lib/mysql2/client.rb:58:in `connect': Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (Mysql2::Error)
    from /home/wasif/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/lib/mysql2/client.rb:58:in `initialize'
    from /home/wasif/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `new'
    from /home/wasif/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `mysql2_connection'
    from /home/wasif/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
    from /home/wasif/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
    from /home/wasif/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
    from /home/wasif/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
    from /home/wasif/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
    from /home/wasif/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /home/wasif/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
    from /home/wasif/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
    from /home/wasif/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /home/wasif/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
    from /home/wasif/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
    from /home/wasif/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
    from /home/wasif/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
    from /home/wasif/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:88:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /home/wasif/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/wasif/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/wasif/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/wasif/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /home/wasif/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/wasif/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /home/wasif/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /home/wasif/projects/Sites/simple_cms/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/wasif/projects/Sites/simple_cms/config.ru:3:in `require'
    from /home/wasif/projects/Sites/simple_cms/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/wasif/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/wasif/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /home/wasif/projects/Sites/simple_cms/config.ru:in `new'
    from /home/wasif/projects/Sites/simple_cms/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /home/wasif/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    from /home/wasif/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /home/wasif/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    from /home/wasif/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    from /home/wasif/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
    from /home/wasif/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
    from /home/wasif/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    from /home/wasif/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/wasif/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /home/wasif/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

please help me how to resolve this error... thanks!

Comment: Try to login to your mysql server using `mysql -u root` from terminal and ensure that the parameters in `config/database.yml` are correct for your environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the password is not set.
In your database.yml you should specify the password for your DB. E.g: if you have set the password on your devlopment pc to: root, it should look like this:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: your_db_name
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: root
  socket: 'depending on your os something like:' /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Also I recommend not to check this file into your VCS. Make a copy of it, call it database.example.yml and put in there your config and a placeholder for the password.

Comment: what happens if you enter mysql -u root? if you can login there is no root pw set. So you can remove the password line from your yml

Comment: actually i was using a wrong syntax in yml file... when i check that did that correctly then it worked. and now its fine! :)